# Valid/Invalid Classes not being added to prefilled text fields

Tags: css, validation, materialize

I am using the MaterializeCSS framework and I am dynamically populating text inputs. One problem I am having is that the `valid` and `invalid` css classes are not being added to my fields until I focus the field.

Even when I call `M.updateTextFields()`, it does not add the CSS classes.

To see an example of what I mean, go to [MaterializeCSS Text Inputs](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html#input) page and go to the Prefilling Text Inputs section. The input field will not show the green highlight until you focus on the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it with jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus().blur();
});
```

After the DOM being load, `focus()` select all inputs and `blur()` deselect them. So after this you can see invalid input values if they are exist.

Here is an example : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/vg2u4krb/27/)